# Printing 0110 as palindrome

Tags: c, while-loop, numbers, reverse, palindrome

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, reverse = 0, temp;

   printf("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome or not\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   temp = n;

   while( temp != 0 )
   {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + temp%10;
      temp = temp/10;
   }

   if ( n == reverse )
      printf("%d is a palindrome number.\n", n);
   else
      printf("%d is not a palindrome number.\n", n);

   return 0;
}
```

The above code will check whether a number is palindrome or not.It work fine.If you input 151 it will say it is a palindrome number.However if you input 0110 it will print not palindrome.Although i know 0110 is actually 110,but my professor says what to do which will print numbers like 011 and 001100 as palindrome.What to do any idea?

Comment: You have to read the numbers as strings if you do not want to loose the leading `0`s. This will make the palindrome check more effective too.

Comment: "but my professor says what to do which will print numbers like 011 ..." - if your professor told you, what is the problem? You should ask him to detail if you don't understand what he means. We are no clairvoyants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the input using a string (array of chars). I have updated your code to use the same -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_len (char *inp) {
   int curr_len = 0;
   for (curr_len=0; inp[curr_len] != '\0'; curr_len++);
   return curr_len-1;
}

int main()
{
   int palindrome = 1;
   char *inp = (char *) malloc (100*sizeof(char *));

   printf("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome or not\n");
   scanf("%s",inp);

   int len = get_len (inp);
   int i;
   for (i=0; i < len/2; i++) 
   {
      if (inp[i] != inp[len-i]) {
        palindrome = 0;
        break;
      }
   }

   if ( palindrome )
      printf("%s is a palindrome number.\n", inp);
   else
      printf("%s is not a palindrome number.\n", inp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check malloc return value, free the allocated memory and no reason to use get_len when there's the strlen function of the string.h lib.

Comment: Yeah, I missed checking the malloc return value. Thank you for pointing that out. Probably should have used an array. 
I wanted my solution to be basic and avoid using library functions. Hence implemented the get_len function.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read a string and then check if is palindrome or not.
Here is your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[64];
    printf("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome or not\n");
    scanf("%63s",buffer);
    size_t dim = strlen(buffer);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (dim / 2); i++) {
        if (buffer[i] != buffer[dim - i - 1]) {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome number.\n", buffer);
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    printf("%s is a palindrome number.\n", buffer);   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this with Int array instead of saving the input in one integer variable.

When you save the integer in your int n, the prefix 0 is neglected. But if you use integer array to store each character in it and then process the array to check for palindrome then the desired result will be correct.

Have a look at arrays in C here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm